# How to Replace the if loop logic for my secnario?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
    A   B   C
A1  1   2   3
B1  4   5   6
C1  7   8   9
```

Using the above (like table) going to get the value for the given header value.
ex: if(column=" A" && row = "B1") then value="4"

without using a often if loops,Is there any idea to fetch the values using C#.

**Note:** The above is not a table or structure getting form DB or any memory objects .It is just a value mapping for the given headervalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to use a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>`, assuming you're using .NET 4. It would work something like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> Table = 
    new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>
{
    { Tuple.Create("A1", "A"), 1 },
    { Tuple.Create("A1", "B"), 2 },
    { Tuple.Create("A1", "C"), 3 },
    { Tuple.Create("B1", "A"), 4 },
    { Tuple.Create("B1", "B"), 5 },
    { Tuple.Create("B1", "C"), 6 },
    { Tuple.Create("C1", "A"), 7 },
    { Tuple.Create("C1", "B"), 8 },
    { Tuple.Create("C1", "C"), 9 },
};

public int this[string row, string column]
{
    get
    {
        return Table[Tuple.Create(row, column)];
    }
}
```

If you're not using .NET 4 you *could* fake it by combining the row and column together, e.g. by concatenating them and adding a slash: "A/A1", "B/B1" etc, and then having a `Dictionary<string, int>`. It's pretty ugly though - I'd be tempted to write my own RowColumn structure to avoid that.

Another alternative would be to keep two dictionaries, each mapping row names or column names to indexes, and then an `int[,]` array for the values. This has the benefit that you can identify when a row or column is invalid. If you really only have a few rows or columns, a simple list of strings would probably be just as fast or faster:

```
private readonly List<string> RowNames = new List<string> { "A1", "B1", "C1" };
private readonly List<string> ColumnNames = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
private readonly int[,] Values = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

public int this[string row, string column]
{
    get
    {
        int rowIndex = RowNames.IndexOf(row);
        if (rowIndex == -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid row specified");
        }
        int columnIndex = ColumnNames.IndexOf(column);
        if (columnIndex == -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid column specified");
        }
        return Values[rowIndex, columnIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: For an old version, you could use `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Comment: @Matthew: True. I don't think I'd want to though :)

Comment: I'm curious why.  I know it's not what it's intended for, but it seems like a close enough substitute.

Comment: @Matthew: Precisely because it's not what it's intended for - when reading the code, I'd be wondering why it was being used. It's also not immediately obvious to me that it overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals` appropriately... I'm checking that now, but the fact that I *have* to check it is an indicator that it's not a great fit.

Comment: looking nice...Thank you .Am using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

You could have a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>`; see [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387036.aspx).  You need to decide if that's a good option for you.